# Having trouble creating proper model relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a Django applicaiton that allows users to follow specific stock tickers and see related news articles based on what they follow. So if a user were to follow "APPl", "AMZN", and "NFLX", they would see news articles for Apple, Amazon and Netflix. I am not sure how to connect certain `Article`s to certain `Stock`s or how to connect certain `Stock`s to specfic `Profile`s. Thanks in advance for any help. My current models are below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_tickers = ?

class Stock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)


class Article(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
followed_tickers = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)
```

then you can get the Stocks user is following as:

```
stocks = user_obj.followed_tickers.all()
```

And the articles based on the Stock user is following as:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(ticker__in=stocks)
```

Comment: it would not let me comment on the other account so I had to make a new one, thank you for the answer but does this mean that the       ticker = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
field is no longer needed? As the bottom two statements are done in views.py correct?

Comment: @Justin You should leave the field `ticket` on your model `Article`: that field is needed for the last line from the answer: `articles = Article.objects.filter(ticker__in=stocks)`

Comment: @Justin and yes, the last two statements from the answer are usually done in the view.

Comment: as commented by @Ralf do not delete ticker field in Article model. ticker field in the Article model will be used to identify who posted the article (e.g. APPl, AMZN or NFLX).